# Hibernate Mapping Performance

Tags: performance, hibernate, orm

i have an simple object mapped by hibernate4 and fetch them like this

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Entity.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.in("id", ids));
System.out.println(crit.list().size());
```

it fetches about 2000 Objects. The pure SQL query takes about 100ms. There are no joins etc. But in hibernate about 4 secs elapse. So the or-mapping/caching etc takes a lot of time. Is there a way to speed it up?

What can you suggest?

the entity looks like this. I have enabled sql logging, but there is no select for the ManyToOne eagerly

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorFormula("type")
public abstract class Entity extends ResourceEntity implements Cloneable {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonProperty(value = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private Type type; //Enum

    private Date expirationDate;

    @NotNull
    private boolean shared;

    private int orderID;

    @ManyToOne
    private MaappedEntity me;

    private String strinvar;
```

mh, even with a plain sql query hibernate seems to be slow

```
SQLQuery sql = session.createSQLQuery("select * from Entity");
System.out.println(sql.list().size());
```

[image]

Comment: Can we see the mapping for your entity? Are you sure that there aren't any properties that are eagerly fetched? That could be the problem.

Comment: You said there are not joins, but there are.  JPA says that @ManyToOne associations are eagerly fetched.  Actually, best case this means a join in the query sent to the database.  Worst case it means n+1 selects.  If you want Entity.me as lazy, you need to explicitly map it as such.  Again that is JPA requirements.

Comment: i' using hibernate and it doesnt fetch eagerly, and there are no additionaly querys. Hibernate just submits one single query, as you can see in the screenshot, the problem is that every single column is processed with nullSafeGet. Thats the slow part